# Diagnose Ubuntu 12.10 (in Dual 12.04-12.10 boot)

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, dual-boot

I find that my Acer Aspire One D270 Netbook (Intel Atom CPU, 2GB DDR3 memory) shows a blank screen with a blinking cursor if I tried booting 12.10 from the bootable USB stick. In fact once, I clicked the "Try from CD" button, saw the blank screen for a while and had dozed off for an hour only to wake up and see the same blank screen again.

Then I installed it alongside my Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit OS) and on booting 12.10, the same blank screen shows up and keeps me indefinitely waiting, until I run out of patience and press the power button, restart and boot my 12.04.

How do I correct this?

Here's what I found the last few lines to be, on scrutinising the problem via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> as our friend here suggests:

```
mountall: Plymouth command failed
mountall: Plymouth command failed
mountall: Plymouth command failed
mountall: Plymouth command failed
mountall: disconnected from Plymouth
```

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly:***

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, and watch the text messages stream passes (as the machine starts). What error message do you see? What does it stop after?

---

***Possible Fix:***

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, login (at the command line), and then run an OS update, to see if this is fixed by recent updates.

Type: **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**

---

***Lastly:***

You will need to do some further diagnostics ..

*With an Intel ATOM CPU, I will assume you are running **32-bit** Ubuntu.*

(correction) *This Acer model has the Intel **Cedarview** / Cedar Trail** CPU / graphics chipset, which is likely the root cause (anyway).*

Can you provide details, from output of **`sudo lshw`**. (**Note:** This can be run from within **12.04 LTS**, and still give much the same results.)

---

**UPDATE:**

The *Acer Aspire One D270* does not support DX10.1, as the Cedar Trail GPU (graphics chip) only officially supports **DirectX 9** (due to driver / design issues).

source:

[NetbookCheck.net > Review: Acer Aspire One D270](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-One-D270-26Dbb-Netbook.73534.0.html)

The netbook is also sold with Windows-7 **32-bit**, and may not fully support **64-bit**. It was left to the (PC/netbook OEM) manufacturer to choose to enable 64-bit, prior to the later **S12nn series** (Dec2012) Intel Atom.

source: (non-authorative)

[wikipedia > Intel Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Atom)

Comment: The 12.04 is a 64-bit OS.

Comment: So this graphics chip not being supported in my 64-bit OS is the cause for this hanging? (Stopping at the "Plymouth" stage) as I indicated in my question above?

Comment: According to the Wiki page cited, the 64-bit problem only applies to Windows. You're already running 12.04 64-bit so you have 64-bit enabled. According to this [ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA3600), the 3.5.x kernel in 12.10 should solve suspend issues (if you are having them). Try `nomodeset` when booting the USB (hit esc once it starts to boot to get to the menu). You may also have a bad burn to USB or a bad download.